# OpenBankProject: DirectLogin missing parameters

Tags: php, api, curl

We are trying to implement the OpenBankProject in an application. Possible auth options are oAuth or DirectLogin ([the DirectLogin docs](https://github.com/OpenBankProject/OBP-API/wiki/Direct-Login)), since we allready are using the second, we chose the fast lane ^^

But now this API keeps returning `These DirectLogin parameters are missing: username, password, consumer_key` while these are set by `curl_setopt`.

Current script:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: DirectLogin username='".urlencode($user)."',password='".urlencode($password)."',consumer_key='".urlencode($secret)."'"
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

If we echo the Authorization part all parameters are there, and provided with correct data. Are we missing something here? Linebreaks between parameters are something like that?

Comment: I was using `CURLOPT_HEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`...

Comment: did you try using double quotation for the parameters values? something like:    
     username=\"".urlencode($user)."\"

Comment: Ah yes :) indeed.. that was the issue, add it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotation for header parameters, like this:

```
username=\"".urlencode($user)."\"
```